# popup image not changing issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create popup under popup but when i try adding any thing in place of images it is not display the old image appears. even close link is not working. Anyone knows why is it happening 
below is my code

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];


// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}
/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}
/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#thumbwrap {
  margin: 75px auto;
  width: 1190px;
  height: 1190px;
}
.thumb {
  float: left;
  /* must be floated for same cross browser position of larger image */
  /* position:relative;*/
  margin: 3px;
}
.thumb img {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.thumb:focus {
  border: 0;
  /* IE6 needs this to show large image */
  z-index: 1;
}
.thumb span {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 70%;
  height: 50%;
  background: grey;
}
.thumb:focus span {
  visibility: visible;
  top: 130px;
  left: 100px;
}
.thumb .x {
  position: absolute;
  top: -11px;
  z-index: 1101;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<img id="myBtn" src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
    <div id="thumbwrap">
      <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""><span><img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt="">jhkjgvfhgcgbfxfdzds\dCS</span>
      </a>
      <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""><span><img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""></span>
      </a>
      <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""><span><img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""></span>
      </a>
      <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""><span><img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""></span>
      </a>
      <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""><span><img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""></span>
      </a>
      <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""><span><img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""></span>
      </a>
      <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""><span><img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""></span>
      </a>
      <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""><span><img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""></span>
      </a>
      <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""><span><img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""></span>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<img id="myBtn2" src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
    <div id="thumbwrap">
      <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-.jpg" alt=""><span><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QjzbjHREC7k" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>jhkjgvfhgcgbfxfdzds\dCS<a class="x" href="#thumbwrap" data-rel="back" style="display:block;">Close</a></span> 
      </a>
      <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""><span><img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""></span>
      </a>
      <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""><span><img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""></span>
      </a>
      <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""><span><img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""></span>
      </a>
      <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""><span><img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""></span>
      </a>
      <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""><span><img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""></span>
      </a>
      <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""><span><img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""></span>
      </a>
      <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""><span><img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""></span>
      </a>
      <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""><span><img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""></span>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What is the expected result?

Comment: <a class="thumb" href="#"><img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt=""><span><img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt="">jhkjgvfhgcgbfxfdzds\dCS</span></a>

Comment: here in this line when i try adding another image its not allowing

Comment: Nor i am able to add any link in it

Comment: Lets say after jhkjgvfhgcgbfxfdzds\dCS i tried adding a link <a href.... its not allowing

Comment: eg: <span><img src="http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/images/jamie-small1.jpg" alt="">jhkjgvfhgcgbfxfdzds\dCS <a href="#" data-rel="back" ">Close</a></span>

Comment: Close is not appearing nor the a tag i check in inspect its not showing. but it is there in the source code but not appearing on browser

Comment: Again I don't understand the problem. Can you give me the steps to reproduce the problem? (for example: 1. click on a image. 2. click on the button. etc.)